# Cannot see Request or Response Cookie headers on external device phonegap app

Tags: cookies, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, httponly, safari-web-inspector

While developing a phonegap application, I can see the SetCookie header in responses from XHR login requests to an API I am using. As expected, when I inspect subsequent requests, I see the cookie being sent. I can also see that it is an `httpOnly` cookie, so I can't store it using scripts.

However, in the Chrome dev tools "Resources" I have no trouble deleting the cookie if I want to.

Yet, when I am running the application on an external iOS or Android device, using the Safari or Chrome Web Inspectors for each respective device, I can't see the cookies in the "Resources" panel. I don't see the cookie headers in requests or responses, either, yet somehow my requests are fine.

Is this a security measure, or is there an bug in my app/API to do with cookies?